# How can I add delay between samplers in Parallel Controller

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to have only 160-170 milliseconds delay between 2 HTTP Requests.If I don't use any Controllers or use a Controller other than Parallel, the delay is over 500 milliseconds. If I use a Parallel Controller, the delay is 15 milliseconds. I tried adding JSR223 timer or Beanshell timer as a child in one of the 2 HTTP Requests within Parallel Controller, but ended up with Java SocketException error. I tried Constant timer as a child, but that did not pause; the 2 requests had only 15ms gap. Can someone help? BTW, the Parallel Controller is within Throughput Controller if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add delay "between" samplers in the Parallel Controller because there is no any "between", the Parallel Controller executes all its children **in parallel**

With regards to other approaches most probably the way you're introducing the delay works according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) and not to your expectations.

A Timer is being executed **before** each Sampler in its scope so if you want to create a delay between Samplers - you need to put a timer as a child of the 2nd sampler or use [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler instead.